# Filter paged items using KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I'm new to knockoutJS and so far I like it. I have one problem of many to come. I have a project where I'm displaying messages from a DB. These messages have categories and I want to be able to apply paging as well as filter by category depending on the link a user clicks on the navigation side of my single page app. So far I'm able to apply paging as illustrated in the following code:

```
self.pagedItems = ko.computed(function () {
        var array = ko.observableArray(data.ChannelMessages);
        var indexOfFirstItemOnCurrentPage = (((self.page() * 1) - 1) * (self.itemsPerPage() * 1));          
        var pageArray = array2.slice(indexOfFirstItemOnCurrentPage, indexOfFirstItemOnCurrentPage + (self.itemsPerPage() * 1));
        return pageArray;
    });
```

`pagedItems` contains messages with private category and public category. I want by default the public category messages to be displayed and when a user clicks on a private(inbox) navigation link private category messages are displayed. How do I go about this as far as filtering is concerned? I know I will have to used templates in addition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using the arrayFilter function in knockout.

First, add an observable for your filter (Private/Public):

```
self.filterCategory = ko.observable('Public');
```

Then modify your self.pagedItems computed's return value:

```
    var pageArray = ...
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(pageArray, function (item) {
        return item.category === self.filterCategory();
    });
});
```

**Please note** that I assumed category is a property on your items.  :-)

Later you can change filterCategory and the computed will automatically recompute.

There's some information on arrayFilter here: http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html

**Extra information in reply to your comment**

Here's a quick sample I wrote:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.0.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var rawMessages = ko.observableArray([]),
            category = ko.observable('Public'),
            pageSize = ko.observable(25),
            pageIndex = ko.observable(0),
            filteredMessages = ko.computed(function () {
                return ko.utils.arrayFilter(rawMessages(), function (m) {
                    return m.category === category();
                });
            });

        // Changing category resets page index.
        category.subscribe(function () {
            pageIndex(0);
        });

        // For binding.
        var model = {
            pageCount: ko.computed(function () {
                return Math.ceil(filteredMessages().length / pageSize());
            }),

            messages: ko.computed(function () {
                var start = pageIndex() * pageSize();
                return filteredMessages().slice(start, start + pageSize());
            }),

            back: function () {
                pageIndex(Math.max(pageIndex() - 1, 0));
            },

            next: function () {
                pageIndex(Math.min(model.pageCount() - 1, pageIndex() + 1));
            },

            category: category
        };

        // Some test data.
        for (var i = 1; i <= 500; i++) {
            rawMessages.push({
                subject: 'Message number ' + i.toString(),
                category: ['Public', 'Private'][Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)]
            });
        }

        $(function () {
            // DOM is ready now
            ko.applyBindings(model);
        });
</script>
</head>
<body>

    Page count: <span data-bind="text: pageCount"></span><br />
    Page index: <span data-bind="text: pageIndex"></span><br />
    Category: <select data-bind="options: ['Public', 'Private'], value: category"></select><br />

    <br />

    <div data-bind="foreach: messages">
        <div>
            [<span data-bind="text: category"></span>] <span data-bind="text: subject"></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <br />

    <button type="button" data-bind="click: back">Back</button> <button type="button" data-bind="click: next">Next</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works like a charm, however I'm now having another problem with totalpages calculation:   

code self.totalPages = ko.computed(function () {
 return Math.ceil(this.messages().length / this.itemsPerPage());
        }, this);
 
this.messages refers to the unfiltered array. if I replace it with the filtered and paged pagedItems the total page count is 1, 
I feel that the solution is to filter then page, but how do I accomplish this?

Comment: I would probably divide and conquer this problem.  Have a raw messages buffer, a filtered messages buffer, then a messages computed based on the filtered messages and your page index / size.  I've added a sample to my reply.  Save it to a .html file and open in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
self.isShowPrivate = ko.observable(false);
self.pagedItems = ko.computed(function () {
    var array = ko.observableArray(data.ChannelMessages);
    var indexOfFirstItemOnCurrentPage = (((self.page() * 1) - 1) * (self.itemsPerPage() * 1));
    var pageArray = getMessages(indexOfFirstItemOnCurrentPage, indexOfFirstItemOnCurrentPage + (self.itemsPerPage() * 1), self.isShowPrivate());
    function getMessages(ParameterizedThreadStart, end, showPrivate)
    {
        if (showPrivate)
        // your logic to get private as well as public
        esle
        // your logic to get  public only
    }
    return pageArray;
});
```

You need to bind isShowPrivate property to your checkbox in the UI.